# loop in django views by "str" method

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name_text, self.surname_text)
```

This is my view:

```
def index(request):
    people_list = People.objects.all()
    ######output = ', '.join([p.name_text for p in people_list])
    output = ', '.join([People for p in people_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

I want to see a page which shows all the people with name and also surname that is located in the database divided by ", ", but I don't know how to do that loop. It's likely that I must use the def "**str**" of the class People but I don't know how.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you joining them at all? You should have a template instead where you can iterate over the People *model*s

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which calls the `People.__str__()` for each entry in your `people_list`.

```
def index(request):
    people_list = People.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join([str(p) for p in people_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

---

You have an error in your original snippet when you're attempting to join the list of people as a string:

```
output = ', '.join([People for p in people_list])
```

You're generating a list of uninstantiated classes (not the resulting instances or objects of those classes), replacing your list of people.